# Why the pattern is not displayed

Tags: html, svg

Why the pattern is not displayed inside the circle?

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="pattern" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" width="10%" height="10%">
      <polygon points="569.2 518 396 618 222.8 518 222.8 318 396 218 569.2 318" fill="none" stroke="orange" />
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  
  <circle cx="50"  cy="50" r="50" stroke="black" fill="url(#pattern)" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few reasons why your SVG doesn't *appear* to be showing anything.

- 1. Your pattern is defined as only taking up 10% of the container shape (`width=10% height=10%`) . this is fine, bit if your container area is only 50px then you're only able to use `5px by 5px` for each iteration of the pattern.
- 2. Coupled with (2), your circle is defined as only 50px diameter, so you're telling the SVG to show only the outline on a shape that takes up a proportion of only 10% of the contents of a circle only 50px wide... so your shape would **at most** be 5px wide; yet your shape within the viewbox area actually uses barely half of this viewbox zone (which is 1000x1000).
- 3. and *then* because you have `fill=none` and `stroke=orange` your pattern is only an outline (stroke width 1 default) so this is why the pattern is being rounded down to zero -- ie being invisible;

     because the cascade of containers are all smaller than the vector viewbox draw area defined as 1000 - so with a viewbox of 1000 and a default stroke width of 1 then when you scale this down to a circle of 50px your line is so small as to be worthless and has to be ignored by the browser as it is far less than 1px (browser pixel) in size.

     **THIS** is why you can't see the line in the circle.

## Example Fixes:

- Circle size is increased to 100px for clarity;
- `Pattern` scalar zoom is increased to 20% width and height for clarity
- Polygon Stroke-width is manually set to being thicker (so more obvious: 2%).

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="pattern" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" width="20%" height="20%">
      <polygon points="569.2,518 396,618 222.8,518 222.8,318 396,218 569.2,318" fill="none" stroke="orange" stroke-width="2%" />
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  
  <circle cx="200"  cy="200" r="100" stroke="black" fill="url('#pattern')" />
</svg>
```

Comment: @RobertLongson I suspected this as I wrote it but didn't double check it as a I felt comma pairs are better for a human to assess what's going on! Anywho, updated. Thanks.